# Table not Rendering properly with vuejs

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I have vuejs component that generates the rows for a table. The code for the component is below.

The component loads the value above the table without `is='constitutionrow'` line, but with the `is` keyword, and the following error occurred:

> error of Uncaught RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded

Any suggestion on how to fix it would help.

```
    Vue.component('constitutionrow', {props: ['id','fid','jlpcandidate','constitution','pnpcandidate','votesjlp','votespnp'],
template:
" <tr 'constitutionrow'>" +
"<td> {{ id }}</td>" +
"<td>{{ fid }}</td>" +
"<td>{{ constitution }}</td> " +
"<td>{{ jlpcandidate }}</td>"  +
"<td>{{ pnpcandidate }}</td>" +
"<td>{{ votesjlp }}</td>"+
"<td>{{ votespnp }}</td>" +
" <td class='center'>" +
"<div>" +
"<a id='' class='glyphicon glyphicon-edit editbtn'  v-on:click='editRecord()'></a>" +
"</div>" +
"</td>" +
" </tr>",

data: function ()
 {

    return {

        hidden: true,
        show: false,
        selectedAnswerer:'',
    }
},
methods: {
    editRecord:function()
    {

        $('.editbtn').colorbox({
            html:"" +
            "<div id='editformConstituency'  class='form-group'>" +
            " <label >Fid</label> <input type='text'  v-model='fid' value='self.' class='form-control'> " +
            " <label >Constitution</label> <input type='text'  v-model='constitution' class='form-control'>"+
            " <label >JLP Candidate</label> <input type='text'  v-model='jlpCandidate' class='form-control'>"+
            " <label >PNP Candidate</label><input type='text'  v-model='phpCandidate' class='form-control'>" +
            " <label >Votes JLP </label> <input type='text'  v-model='votesJLP' class='form-control'>"+
            " <label >Votes PNP </label> <input type='text'  v-model='votesPnp' class='form-control'>"+
            "<button v-on:click='submitEdit()'>Submit</button>"+
            "  <script src='http://localhost/ElectionMapApplication/public/js/vuecontrollers/editFormConstituency.js'></script>" +
            "</div>",
            width: "75%",
            height: "75%",
            onComplete: function(){
                var bg = $.colorbox.element().data('bg');
                $('#cboxLoadedContent').css('backgroundColor', bg);
            }
        });
        },
}});
```

Values Appear Above table 
[Values Appear Above Table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/d8f54.png)

Answer (score 0):

That error generally means you have a function that is calling itself. The HTML in there is your template for the constitutionrow component, but within it you have a `<tr is='constitutionrow'>` which is creating another constitutionrow component.  This would keep going endlessly.

Comment: ok but even without the is keyword the values appear above the table as you can see in the image that is in the link. Any suggestion on how to fix it

Comment: Any elements inside a `<table>` element MUST BE `<tr>` elements.  If you try to put a `<div>` inside a table, for instance, it will appear outside the table, like you have here.  So I would guess your code says something like `<table><constitutionrow></constitutionrow></table> and HTML is kicking it outside the table.

Comment: What if you make the template for `constitutionrow` only include the `<td>` elements and not the `<tr>` wrapper.  Then within your `<table>` you could place something like `<tr is='constitutionrow' v-for="....">`